# Spark Job in Synapse cannot be viewed in monitoring portal - Error Message is Fetching Failed

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

It is rare and intermittent but there are times when the monitoring portal in Azure Synapse will misbehave and will not show me the details about a completed spark job.  Instead, it displays an error message that says "Fetching Failed".  Screenshot.

[image]

I have not yet found a pattern or explanation.  I reported the problem to CSS support but they are not yet familiar with the error.  I suspect it is a timeout on an internal resource, like a spark history server or something like that.

I realize that some parts of the Synapse platform are proprietary but it borrows significantly from OSS spark.  Does anyone have an idea what might take so long, when retrieving the U/I for a completed livy batch?  Is it Azure storage accounts that are performing badly?  Or is it a "spark history server"?  Is there any reason why they wouldn't wait indefinitely for a response (eg. ten mins)?  Whenever this happens the U/I seems to fail after a short period of time (only ~60 seconds or so).  I haven't found any other patterns.  As you can see above, the error message is nothing more than a small tooltip shown in the upper right of the screen; when I shared with CSS they weren't able to provide any additional guidance or explanation.  So I'm hoping there are synapse users on stack overflow who have encountered this.

```
Side: When things are working properly, the spark job is 
presented with the related jobs/stages/tasks/logs like so:
```

[image]